# Set the value of a button as the value of ng-repeat name.cab_palette

Tags: php, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I want to set the value of a button as the value of a `ng-repeat` `name.cab_palette` and then show the value of the button in another page. 
Kindly advise.

Code - `index.php`

```
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr ng-repeat="name in namesData">
    <td>{{name.id_fiche}}</td>
    <td>{{name.cab_appellation}}</td>
    <td>{{name.cab_palette}}</td>
    <?php  
       echo "<td><button type='button' ng-click='fetchSingleData(name.id_fiche)' class='btn btn-warning btn-xs'>Editer</button></td>" ; 
       echo "<td> <form action='pdf/index.php' TARGET=_BLANK method='POST'> <button class='btn btn-info btn-xs' name='print' value=name.cab_palette >imprimer</button></form></td>" ;                       
    ?>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just set the `value` to `'name.cab_palette'`. If you want the value to be rendered by AngularJS you must change

```
value=name.cab_palette
```

to

```
value="{{ name.cab_palette }}"
```

---

See comment. In your case obviously

```
echo "<td> ...name='print' value='{{ name.cab_palette }}'>imprimer</button></form></td>" ;
```

Because you wrap all the other attributes into `''` and your string into `""`.

Comment: it is not working : Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' in

Comment: @OussamaFathallah, yes if you just insert it as is it will raise a parse error, because you are using quotes an alternative way. The convention is to use `''` around your strings,`""` around attributes.  So in your case, you must use `value='{{ name.cab_palette }}'` or correct your echoes.

Comment: i don't know how to thank you @davidkonrad. it has been two days searching for the answer. God bless you

Comment: @OussamaFathallah, Gee  That sounds frustrating, makes me happy I could help :)